# Sending array with writeObject()

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, air

Currently I'm working on a turn based multiplayer game using stage3D. When the server sends a object for example the code below everything goes very smooth on the client side.

```
package models 
{
    public class Player 
    {
        public var type:String = "player";
        private var _action:String;
        private var _id:int;

        private var _username:String;
        private var _nickname:String;

        public function Player() 
        {

        }

        public function get id():int 
        {
            return _id;
        }

        public function set id(value:int):void 
        {
            _id = value;
        }

        public function get username():String 
        {
            return _username;
        }

        public function set username(value:String):void 
        {
            _username = value;
        }

        public function get nickname():String 
        {
            return _nickname;
        }

        public function set nickname(value:String):void 
        {
            _nickname = value;
        }

        public function get action():String 
        {
            return _action;
        }

        public function set action(value:String):void 
        {
            _action = value;
        }
        public function toString():String
        {
            return("id: " + id + " username: " + username + " nickname: " + nickname + "");
        }
    }

}
```

But when I put an array in the object the array always returns length 0. And now I'm a bit out of options. I used registerClassAlias

```
package models 
{
    /**
     * ...
     * @author RB
     */
    public class ListOfPlayers
    {
        public var type:String = "list_of_players";

        private var _list:Array = new Array();

        public function ListOfPlayers() 
        {

        }

        public function remove(i:int):void 
        {
            _list.slice(i);
        }

        public function add(player:Player):void 
        {
            _list.push(player);
        }

        public function get list():Array 
        {
            return _list;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding public setter for the array? I think that's your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that actually stores and retrieves the Player class in a SharedObject?  Double-check the Flash Player's default size limit for SOs . . . it may be turned off, or too small (this will be a problem for individual users, so you will have to verify FP's SO size setting for the final game).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you should either declare your array as public, or implement the flash.utils.IExternalizable interface (readExternal() and writeExternal() methods).

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html

> The IExternalizable interface provides control over serialization of a class as it is encoded into a data stream. The writeExternal() and readExternal() methods of the IExternalizable interface are implemented by a class to allow customization of the contents and format of the data stream (but not the classname or type) for an object and its supertypes. Each individual class must serialize and reconstruct the state of its instances. These methods must be symmetrical with the supertype to save its state. These methods supercede the native Action Message Format (AMF) serialization behavior.
>
> If a class does not implement, nor inherits from a class which
>   implements, the IExternalizable interface, then an instance of the
>   class will be serialized using the default mechanism of public members
>   only. As a result, private, internal, and protected members of a class
>   will not be available.